# Azure storage turn off automatic decompression

Tags: python, azure, azure-sdk, azure-sdk-python

Hi I'm using python with the azure-sdk to download files from a storage blob. The following code is what I use.

```
BLOB_SERVICE = BlockBlobService(account_name=AZURE_BLOB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_NAME, account_key=AZURE_BLOB_SERVICE_ACCOUNT_KEY)

cloud_globals.BLOB_SERVICE.get_blob_to_path(
            guid,
            name,
            path,
        )
```

The download works but Azure or the SDK decompresses my gzipped files on the fly when the files are fetched. I need the files to be gzipped and I would prefer to download the files as they are on the storage. Is there any way to turn off this behaviour?

Comment: It seams Azure sdk is not responsible in itself for the deflation it could be that it's requirement requests 2.9.2 does it automatically. I will have a look at this

Comment: Hi, try to focus on the content type and content encoding settings? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46612595/python-azure-uploaded-file-content-type-changed-to-application-octet-stream

Comment: @JayGong It seems that request indeed does automatic gzipp decompression. Why should I focus on the encoding settings?

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, your issue is due to your blob properties. You could check it on the portal and need to set the `Content_Encoding = NULL`.

[image]

I tested your code and the gz file could be downloaded normally.

If I set the `Content_Encoding = gzip` which is corresponding to my file foramt, the `gz` file will be decompressed when the file is fetched as same as you. You could refer to this [doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Encoding).

Comment: I think that solution would be problematic as I have several thousand of files. I would then have to script something to do that.

Comment: @PabloJomer Why not just test one file first to locate the key of issue?